# Change JVM Properties Using WebSphere MBeans

Tags: java, jvm, websphere

I'm trying to create a java program that will edit the class path properties of the JVM on WebSphere. I am now able to connect the program to the server and also find the node, but I don't know what to do next. Which MBean should I use to be able to find the JVM Classpath and configure it? I know I can edit it on the AdminConsole itself, but for this task, I would really have to do it using a Java Program.

I am also not allowed to use wsadmin and jacl/jython scripts.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Expi 
{
    private AdminClient adminClient;
    private ObjectName nodeAgent;
    private AdminService adminSF;

    String hostName = "localhost";
    String hostPort = "8880";
    String nodeName = "node1";
    String servName = "server1";

    public static void main(String [] args) throws NamingException, AdminException
    {
        Expi xp = new Expi();

        xp.createAdminClient();
        xp.getNodeAgentMBean(nodeName);
        xp.testMB();
    }

    private void createAdminClient()
    {
         // Set properties for the connection 
        Properties connectProps = new Properties();
        connectProps.setProperty(
        AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
        connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, hostName);
        connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, hostPort);
        connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, hostName);
        connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "false");
        // Connection Status Update
        try
        {
            adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);
            System.out.println("Connected to SOAP Connection!");
        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception creating admin client: " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }       
    }

     private void getNodeAgentMBean(String nodeName) throws NamingException
        {
            // Finding the specified node
            try
            {
                String query = "WebSphere:type=Server,node="+ nodeName + ",*";
                ObjectName queryName = new ObjectName(query);
                Set s = adminClient.queryNames(queryName, null);
                if (!s.isEmpty())
                {
                    nodeAgent = (ObjectName)s.iterator().next();   
                    System.out.println("Specified Node Found:" + nodeName);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Node agent MBean was not found");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedObjectNameException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            catch (java.lang.Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    private void testMB() //find the correct MBean and use it to edit the values
    {
        AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService();
        AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory();

    }

}
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the admin command using the AdminClient API. It is very difficult for to find out specific action since it is not well documented like JACL or JYTHON.

Sample available below for simple "**listNodes**" command. You can use the same approach to "**listServers**" and get the specific server object you want to modify. Once the server object is obtained, you can look at the same documentation below for executing command on specific target object.

```
AdminCommand cmd = cmdMgr.createCommand("listNodes");
cmd.setConfigSession(session);

AsyncCommandClient  asyncCmdClientHelper = 
new AsyncCommandClient(session, null);
asyncCmdClientHelper.execute(cmd);

CommandResult result = cmd.getCommandResult(); 
if (result.isSuccessful()) {
    System.out.println("Successfully executed the command");
    System.out.println("Result: ");
    Object resultData = result.getResult();
    if (resultData instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] resDataArr = (Object[])resultData;
        for (Object resData : resDataArr) {
            System.out.println(resData);
        }   
    } else {
        System.out.println(resultData);
    }
 } else {
    System.out.println("Failed to execute the command");
    result.getException().printStackTrace();
}
```

Documentation Link : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1303_samantary/1303_samantary.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried to the documentation for the API, but not everything is there. There were some functions that's not listed on the doc. I have only one server with one node, do you have any idea on how to specifically target the JVM configurations there? I would only be needing to clear out what's written on the classpath configuration. I have been trying to find something, but I wasn't really able to find anything yet. I'm wondering if I'm doing the wrong thing or working with the wrong MBean.

Comment: Let me check and get back. I have written some thing similar to spit out all the configuration objects.

Comment: Cool! Hope you find it. Thanks bro!